# Android Voice Control - don't get all words

Tags: java, android, voice

I have a problem with my Voice Control.

If I say “select”, the voice control recognizes it and returns the word = “select”.
But if I say “bar code”, the voice control recognizes nothing and returns word = “”.

But this problem is only with “bar code” ! Every word (“next”, “forward”…) works.
Maybe do you know something which can help solving the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your pronunciation of the word is clear?

Comment: Yes i think it is clear
Sometimes it works then not...but now it's not working

Comment: OK. Now spit out that damn chewing gum!

Comment: Is there any possibility to solve it?